# Binding to a QML widget's rendered height

Tags: qt, layout, qml

Let's say I have a text field and a button. I'd like to set the button's width and height to the text field's rendered height but it's not working.

[image: Rendering]

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.10

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 200
    color: "#f0eded"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    RowLayout {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

        TextField {
            id: txtPassword
            text: qsTr("Text Field")
            font.pointSize: 22
        }

        Button {
            id: btnSubmit
            width: txtPassword.height
            height: txtPassword.height
            text: qsTr("»")
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like the button is ignoring the binding to the text field's height. My theory is that since this attribute isn't explicitly set, QML doesn't know which width/height to assign to the button.

What would be the proper way to take on the text field's actual rendered height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use layout you should not use width or height, in case you want to obtain the same height you must use `implicitWidth` or `implicitHeight`, if you want the item to occupy the height of the row then you must use `Layout.fillHeight: true`. In the same way for the width.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.10

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 200
    color: "#f0eded"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    RowLayout {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

        TextField {
            id: txtPassword
            text: qsTr("Text Field")
            font.pointSize: 22
        }

        Button {
            id: btnSubmit
            implicitHeight: txtPassword.implicitHeight // or Layout.fillHeight: true
            implicitWidth: implicitHeight
            text: qsTr("»")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Or instead of using [`RowLayout`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-rowlayout.html) you could use a [`Row`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-row.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.10

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 200
    color: "#f0eded"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Row {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        spacing: 5

        TextField {
            id: txtPassword
            text: qsTr("Text Field")
            font.pointSize: 22
        }

        Button {
            id: btnSubmit
            width: txtPassword.height
            height: txtPassword.height
            text: qsTr("»")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]